# Books on Sephardi STaM Safrut

Tags: halacha, product-recommendation, jewish-books, sephardi-mizrachi-eastern, safrus

I am studying safrut (with an Ashkenazi teacher), but I and my havruta partner are both interested in also learning the Sephardi script for STaM. We are (G!d-willing) about to finish learning a book that my teacher recommended, [Masoret Tsurat haOtiot](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/48890), and are hoping to find other books — either historical or modern — that describe the halakhot of STaM from a Sephardi, Spanish-Portuguese, or North African perspective. The other books I've been able to find so far are [Qol haReMeZ](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/41061) (Moshe Zacuto) and [LeDavid Emet](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/7896) (HiDA).

Does anyone know of any others?

Comment: Yeriot Shelomo by Rav Shlomo Moallem https://yadrefael.com/books/